# Validating entry for GtkCellRendererText, g_signal_connect gpointer to struct contains garbage

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I'm trying to come up with a general purpose library to remove a lot of the set up work for GTK, so that the GTK code can be hidden away neatly. Mostly it works okay.  The problem I have is with providing a validator for an edited Cell.  If I put the validation code into my tree_cell_edited function then it works fine - but I don't want to do that because that messes with my nicely reusable libraries (they won't be reusable anymore!)

What I tried to do is implement tree_cell_edited as follows:

```
void tree_cell_edited (GtkCellRendererText *cell, const gchar *path_string, const gchar *new_text, gpointer model_definition_ptr) {
    struct model_definition *model_def = (struct model_definition*)model_definition_ptr;

    GtkTreeModel *model = gtk_tree_view_get_model(GTK_TREE_VIEW(model_def->tableview));

    if (model_def->validator_ptr == NULL) {
        g_print("Validator is null\n");
    }

    GtkTreePath *path = gtk_tree_path_new_from_string (path_string);
    GtkTreeIter iter;
    gint column = GPOINTER_TO_INT (g_object_get_data (G_OBJECT (cell), "column_number"));
    gtk_tree_model_get_iter (model, &iter, path);

    char *upd_text=(char *)malloc( strlen(new_text) * 2 ); // need to malloc twice the size of the text to allow modification - need a better solution later
    strcpy(upd_text, new_text);

    if ( ( ((struct model_definition*)model_definition_ptr)->validator_ptr == NULL ) || (*model_def->validator_ptr)(cell, path_string, (char **) &upd_text, model) ) {
        gtk_tree_store_set(GTK_TREE_STORE (model), &iter, column, upd_text, -1);
    }

    free(upd_text);
    gtk_tree_path_free (path);
}
```

Which is set up as follows:

```
g_signal_connect (cell, "edited", G_CALLBACK (tree_cell_edited), &model_def);
```

The model_def struct is set up as:

```
typedef struct model_definition {
    bool (*validator_ptr)();
    GtkWidget *tableview;
} model_definition;
```

and

```
model_definition model_def;
model_def.validator_ptr = &valid_edit;
model_def.tableview = tableview;
```

where valid_edit is my validation function.  When I try this with valid_edit set to NULL then Validator is NULL never gets printed. When I use this style of code I get `invalid cast from 'GtkWindow' to 'GtkTreeView' errors` some of the time but not all of the time - whereas if I do the more traditional passing of the GtkTreeModel in to tree_cell_edited it all works fine.

Whats the issue here?  Do I not have complete freedom over what I pass into whatever function I call with g_signal_connect for an edited cell?  Is there something embarrassing and obviously wrong with my code?  Is there a better way of calling my validation routine, bearing in mind that I don't want it in my Gtk code (for reasons of reusability).

If it helps, this code needs to be usable on Linux, Windows and macOS - so if it's a clever but platform specific trick then it isn't going to work.

Comment: Just to be sure: are you allocating `model_definition model_def;` on the stack or as a global variable?

Comment: On the stack.  When I tried it slightly differently, using a global variable, it works fine - it'll do as a workaround for now, but I'm a bit prejudiced against global variables.

Comment: if you set something to NULL (valid_edit) then its address (validator_ptr) is never NULL